# Tableau: How to create an exact match formula for a wildcard match search bar?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am trying to make a wildcard match search bar in Tableau that will only return exact matches to the text that is inputted in the search bar.

I started with:

```
IF (CONTAINS([Title]," "+[Search Parameter]+" ")) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

Then quickly realized that this only returns values that have a space at the front and end of the search word/phrase. It also only showed titles that contained 2 spaces in them when the search bar was blank. Then I tried this:

```
IF (CONTAINS([Title]," "+[Search Parameter]+" ")) OR 

STARTSWITH([Title],[Search Parameter]+" ") OR 

ENDSWITH([Title]," "+[Search Parameter])) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

It didn't seem to return any values with a space either before or after the search term. The search terms vary wildly so I didn't see a great way to use a Regex formula.

I would also like to add 2 more search bars, one that will only return values that start with the search text and the other that will only return values that end with the search text. Ideally, none of these searches would interfere with each other and the starts with/ends with search bars could be used at the same time.

I appreciate any help I can get with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how does your data in Title field, a simple 2 or 3 rows will be fine to know what you are doing

Comment: The title field has about 20,000+ rows that look something like this:

Tell us about your personality and we'll match you with a TV show
The English vocab quiz
How well do you know world history?
Can you identify these movies?

None of the rows have any information that is consistent. Hope this helps explain things better. My search parameter is set to:
Date type: String 
Allowable values: All

Comment: ok if you add date as search then what is your expected output?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would expect the output to be every row with that exact date in the same exact format I wrote in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
IF FIND([Title],[Search Parameter]) <> 0
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END
```

`Find` will give the position of the character and returns a integer in found and 0 if nothing found, here you don't give any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @d_kennetz added explanation